# What kinds of fish tend to have a rapid death after being caught?

Tags: zoology, nutrition, ichthyology, death, pain

I am asking this question because I am trying to make my diet less cruelty-oriented, for this reason this question can be related to trolley problem since I am coping with an ethical problem trying to minimize the the core aspect i.e. suffering.

On the contrary I would like to know what kinds of fish suffer the least after being caught. I know that shrimps/prawns die very quickly since they cannot breathe out of the water, for instance [here](https://www.quora.com/How-are-prawns-normally-killed) I have read that prawns die after  just a couple of minutes out of water. But for medium/small size fish is different, especially for those which are mass-caught. Not to mention the explosion of bowels caused by rapid pressure variation.

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnHadish I think technical knowledge about pain is required in order to answer